# Swift: How to get data from selected cell?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a table view with list of users. I want to show guest details from firebase to UIALertController. When I clicked on cells, it give's me the details just for the first user, from the first cell.
Here is my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)as! userTableViewCell

   
    if cell.isClicked == true {
        ref = Database.database().reference().child("userInfo").child(uid!).child("users")
        ref.queryOrderedByKey().observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.childrenCount>0{
                self.usersList.removeAll()
                
                for users in snapshot.children.allObjects as![DataSnapshot]{
                    let userObject = users.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                    let userPhoneNumber = userObject?["PhoneNumber"]
                    let userEmail = userObject?["Email"]
                    
                    let user = UserModel(userPhoneNumber: userPhoneNumber as? String, userEmail: userEmail as? String)
                    
                    
                   
                    let phone = user.userPhoneNumber
                    let email = user.userEmail
                    let userInfo = "\(phone!) \n\(email!)"
                    
                    
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "User", message: userInfo, preferredStyle: .alert)
                   
                    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default)
                    alert.addAction(cancelAction)
                    
                    let callAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Call", style: .default) { (action) in
                        if  let number = guestPhoneNumber {
                            guard let url = URL(string: "teleprompt://\(number)") else{
                                return
                                
                            }
                            UIApplication.shared.open(url)
                        }
                    }
                    alert.addAction(callAction)
                    
                    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    self.usersList.append(guest)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should have already retrieved that data from Firebase and stored it in an array so that you can display it in your cell.  When the cell is selected you simply go back to that array using `indexPath.row` and get the data you need.  You shouldn't need to go back to the network.  Even if you do need to get more detail than you already have, you should have the identifier for the record you need and you should be able to fetch that record directly rather than fetching all user details

Comment: @Paulw11 Can you show me through an example how to do it, because I am new to Swift? Thank you

Comment: Well, from what I can see of your code (you haven't shown your `cellForRowAt`) something like `let user = self.userList[indexPath.row]` is all you need.